# If $A$ is an infinite set, prove $A \times A$ is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In this book the infinite set $X$ is defined like this:
$X$ is an infinite set if there exists an injection $f:X \to X$ but $f$ is not onto.
Now for proving this question I figured I would have to use this property: "if $X$ is infinite and $g:X \to Y$ is bijection then $Y$ is an infinite set."
However I don't know how to assign the elements in $A$ to pairs in $A \times A$.
I mean if I was dealing with set of the natural numbers maybe I could define a bijection that can do this for me. But I don't know how to do it in general.
Thank you.

Comment: You could take $f:A\rightarrow A\times A$ as $f(a)=(a,a)$. Note $A$ is injective, so it maps $A$ bijectively onto its image $f(A)$. This means $f(A)\subseteq A\times A$ is also infinite. Now use the fact that any set that contains an infinite subset is also infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be much easier to use your definition (the one about the injection). Let $A$ be infinite, and let $f: A \rightarrow A$ be an injection that is not surjective. Define $g: A \times A \rightarrow A \times A$ by $g(x, y) = (f(x), f(y))$. All you need to do now is show $g$ is injective, but not surjective. Can you do that?